# Google Maps API V3 difference vs Google Maps page

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Inputting this address: "Tokyo, Minatoku, Higashi Azabu 1-9-11" on GoogleMaps, I get a location with coordinates somewhere around 35.65733, 139.7444.

However when i try to get the very same address in the exact same format (just URL encoded spaces) with the API (V3) I get very different coordinates, coordinates 35.6894875, 139.6917064:
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Tokyo,%20Minatoku,%20Higashi%20Azabu%201-9-11&sensor=true

What should I do to get exactly the same service that Google Maps is using?